# Doubts Related to working of torrents?

Tags: networking, bittorrent

I was trying to understand how torrents work?

And after reading a lot on web I now know the basics about it but I have a very
important question related to working of torrents!

In torrents how do **peer-to-peer** connections take place?

Almost all the peers have **private-IP(for e.g 192.x.x.x)** addresses then how does connections take place **without a server(As I have read: There is no server involved in torrents) ?**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

There are a few alternatives:

1. Peers behind NAT simply don't connect to other peers behind NATs. This creates two classes of peers, where the ones that are connectable will have an advantage when trading pieces, and typically achieve faster download rates.
2. Peers behind NAT use UPnP or NAT-PMP to set up port forwarding in order to be connectable by other peers
3. peers using uTP and Peer exchange can support a simple hole-punching mechanism (uTorrent and libtorrent supports this for instance). A peer can help in introducing two of its connections to each other, they try to connect to at the same time and of one of them have a full-cone NAT, they are very likely to succeed in establishing the connection.
4. Peers supporting DHT and uTP may use a relatively new feature where the port announced to the DHT is derived from their UDP packets. Using the same socket for DHT and uTP increases the chances that a peer behind a full-cone NAT can accept incoming connections without UPnP or NAT-PMP set up. Simply because the DHT traffic will keep a pinhole open on the NAT.

If you have a swarm of only peers behind symmetric NATs, nobody is going to be able to connect to anyone else, and bittorrent is not going to work. In practice (at least in moderately large swarms) there are always some peers that are connectable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the development of libtorrent! I still have another specific little question. For what I understood, the trackers are not going to do hole-punching for peers So if I created a torrent and seed from my PC with only full-cone Carrier-Grad NAT, my friend on another full-cone Carrier-Grad NAT will never be able to download unless either of us moved to a third client with on a fully-connectable net joined the downloading. I'm I right? And if we setup router correctly to use UPnP | NAT-PMP, it doesn't matter how much layer of home routers we are behind?

Comment: Forgive me about my ignorance. The situation I'm facing is, me and my friend are both behind router and setup UPnP and NAT-PMP correctly. qBittorrent can detect my external IP and reports port mapping using UPnP correctly. And we are both behind to different Carrier-Grad NAT. Then, I tried to create a torrent and seed it. I also added several trackers to the torrent. The thing is he can't download after a period of time at all. Both of us can see each other's external IP:PORT for sometime in qBittorrent "peer" list, though, but the connection seems can't be established and disappear later.